# Mapping request payload to variable throws exception when not available for Mule

Tags: json, mule, runtime-error, mule-component

While using MULE, I convert payload received from HTTP request to json object and mapped it to variables. In case, when I do not pass one of the variable, I get exceptions while evaluating the expression.

```
 <flow name="test">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <set-variable variableName="a"              value="#[message.payload.a]"
    <set-variable variableName="b"              value="#[message.payload.b]"
    <logger message="a:  #[a]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
</flow>
```

When the payload is

```
{
    "a": "val1",
    "b": "val2"
}
```

The applications runs fine.

But if the payload is

```
{
   "b": "val2"
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
 ERROR [].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
********************************************************************************
Message               : Execution of the expression "a" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).
Payload               : {b="val2"}
Payload Type          : java.util.LinkedHashMap
Element               : /test/processors/10 @ test:test.xml:47 (Logger)
Element XML           : <logger message="a:  #[a]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
[Error: unresolvable property or identifier: a]
[Near : {... a ....}]
```

Can I check and append the value of variable `'a'` as `NULL` ?

P.S. I would like to use this variable for sending as one of the parameters in payload for some other http request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `#[flowVars.a]` instead of `#[a]` will result in `null` instead of a exception.

Answer (score 1):

Something is not right with your implementation.  After the http listener, the payload is a raw response(JSON), which in any way cannot be access by #[payload.a] or #[payload['a']]. You should add an json to Object(which converts the json to map). From here you could reference it like this #[payload['a']] or #[payload.a]